# NodeJS Google Drive API how to update file

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

Hi I'm trying to update a Google Doc with NodeJS using the Google Drive API and I'm getting this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": null
 }
}
```

Here's the relevant code :

```
var j = new google.auth.JWT(
    creds.client_email,
    null,
    creds.private_key,
    [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
    ]
);
async function refreshTokens() {
    startedWaiting = true;
    return j.authorize((r,t) => {
        startedWaiting = false;
        timeTillNeedRefresh = t["expiry_date"] - Date.now();
        setTimeout(function() {
            refreshTokens();
        //    console.log("doing Q", Q);

        }, timeTillNeedRefresh);

        tokens = t;
        console.log("GOT A TOKEN", tokens);
        Q.forEach(x=>x());
        Q = [];

    });
}

async function start() {
    await refreshTokens();
}
start();
function myFetch(opts) {
    if(!opts) opts = {};
    var cb = opts.cb || empty;
    var headers =  {
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
        'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/0.7.2 (gzip)',
        Authorization:tokens.token_type +" "+ tokens.access_token,
        Accept:"application/json"
    };
    if(opts.headers) {
        for(k in opts.headers) {
            headers[k] = opts.headers[k];
        }
    }
    fetch(
        opts.url 
        || "",
    {
        method:opts.method || "GET",
        headers: headers
    })
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(body => {
            cb(body);

        });
}

updateFile({
    id: "1vebqOamZ9QB4HqfUaQN-U9Zt4y33eij-I21glMvaPVQ",
    content: "hi there"
});

async function allFuncs(tmp) {
    if(tokens === null) {
        console.log("DOING it later")
        Q.push(tmp);
        await refreshTokens();
    } else if(startedWaiting || timeTillNeedRefresh <= 0) {
        console.log("NOT for a while");
        Q.push(tmp);
    } else {
        console.log("THIS is what should happen");
        start = Date.now();
        tmp();
    }
}

async function updateFile(opts) {
    var id = opts.id,
        content = opts.content || "";
    if(id) {
        allFuncs(() => {
            myFetch({
                url:`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/${id}?uploadType=media`,
                method:"PATCH",
                headers: {
                    body: opts.content,
                    "Content-Type": "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
                },
                cb(b) {
                    console.log(b, "DID I DO IT?!");
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I tried looking up what this error means but I couldn't find anything related to nodejs...
Does anyone know if its a header issue or is there any way to fix it?

I don't know if its possible to do wih a service key, or if you HAVE to verify the user in order to do so??

SEEMINGLY if the service key email has edit permissions for the file, it should just be able to edit it at will.

Comment: In order to correctly your situation, can I ask you about your question? 1. Do you want to overwrite Google Document by a text of ``hi there``? 2. Is the Google Document shared with the Service Account? 3. Can you use googleapis of Node.js? 4. Are you required to use only Drive API? For example, how about using Google Docs API?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, Yes, Yes, and I'm currently just using the drive API I didn't know there was a difference between the doc and drive API nowadays, I could use anything I need

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about your question. I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, although I did say that I can use the googleAPI, but I neglected to mentioned that I would be interested in doing it without it; just by using GET requests, do you know how to do that?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm sorry for the inconvenience. And I'm really sorry that my answer was not useful for you. Unfortunately, the file cannot be directly overwritten using GET method. This is the specification. I apologize for this situation. If Web Apps using Google Apps Script is used, the script for overwritten the file is run by requesting to Web Apps with GET method. At that time, Web Apps is required to be created by Google Apps Script and deploy it. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike I think it said somewhere in the documentiation about using PUT instead of get, do you know if thats possible?

Comment: Is that the method for using Web Apps?

Comment: @Tanaike No it was for a server-side script, I prefer NOT to use web apps

Comment: I could understand that you don't want to use Web Apps with Google Apps Script. Can I ask you about the server-side script?

Comment: @Tanaike NodeJS

Comment: In the case that Drive API is used from the script of node.js, PATCH method is required to be used for overwriting the file. You can see the sample script at my answer. drive.files.update of Drive API v3 is https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update

Comment: @Tanaike and without using files.update?

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the file without using files.update method?

Comment: @Tanaike kir-ekct

Comment: I'm sorry. I cannot understand about ``kir-ekct``. Can I ask you about the detail information of it? I apologize for my language skill.

Comment: @Tanaike I just mean "correct" lol "kir-ekct" sound it out..

Comment: I could understand about it. Although I had looked for the method for directly overwriting the file without PUT, PATCH and POST method, unfortunately, I couldn't find it. At Drive API, PUT and PATCH methods are used for it. At batchUpdate of Google Docs API, POST method is used for it. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: @Tanaike No I have no problem using patch and put, just as long as it works, hwo can I do it? When I tried it just didnt wokr

Comment: When you can use PATCH method, you can use the script in my answer. I heard that you can use googleapis of node.js. So I used it. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes but do you know how I can use it without using the googleapis script? Ultimately its just a request, seemingly I shouldn't need an entire library for that

Comment: If googleapis is not used, you cannot also use ``new google.auth.JWT()``. In this case, you want to retrieve the access token without ``new google.auth.JWT()``. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 3):

- You want to overwrite the existing Google Document by a text of `hi there` with Drive API using Service Account.
- The Google Document is shared with the Service Account.
- You can use googleapis.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? In this sample script, I used the files.update method of Drive API.

#### Sample script:

Before you run the script, please set the json file path downloaded when the Service Account is created. And please confirm the file ID of Google Document, again.

```
const stream = require('stream');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const creds = require('###'); // Please set the json file path downloaded when the Service Account is created.
const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    creds.client_email,
    null,
    creds.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],
    null
);

const id = "1vebqOamZ9QB4HqfUaQN-U9Zt4y33eij-I21glMvaPVQ"; // Please set the file ID of Google Document
const content = "hi there"; // Please set the text.

const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: jwtClient});
const buf = Buffer.from(content, 'binary');
const buffer = Uint8Array.from(buf);
var bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
bufferStream.end(buffer);
const media = {
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
    body: bufferStream,
};
drive.files.update({
    fileId: id,
    media: media,
}, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(res.data);
});
```

#### Note:

- When you run the script, the existing Google Document is overwritten. So please be careful this. I recommend to use a sample Document for testing.
- If this script didn't work, please confirm the following points.

  1. Drive API is enabled at API console.
  2. The Service Account can be used.
  3. The Google Document is shared with the Service Account.
  4. The version of googleapis is the latest one.

#### Reference:

- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)

### Edit:

- You don't want to use googleapis.
- You want to overwrite Google Document with a text value without using googleapis.

From your comments, I understood like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? When you run this script, please confirm the following points.

1. About the script,

   - Please set privateKey and clientEmail from JSON file of Service Account.
   - Please set the file ID of the existing Google Document you want to overwrite.
2. Drive API is enabled at API console.
3. The Service Account can be used.
4. The Google Document is shared with the Service Account.
5. The version of googleapis is the latest one.

#### Sample script:

```
const cryptor = require('crypto');
const request = require('request');

// Get access token using Service Account
function getAccessToken(serviceAccount) {
    const scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"];
    const url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
    const header = {
        alg: "RS256",
        typ: "JWT",
    };
    const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    const claim = {
        iss: serviceAccount.clientEmail,
        scope: scopes.join(" "),
        aud: url,
        exp: (now + 3600).toString(),
        iat: now.toString(),
    };
    const signature = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(header)).toString('base64') + "." + Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(claim)).toString('base64');
    var sign = cryptor.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
    sign.update(signature);
    const jwt = signature + "." + sign.sign(serviceAccount.privateKey, 'base64');
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request({
            method: "post",
            url: url,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                assertion: jwt,
                grant_type: "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
            }),
        }, (err, res, body) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
            const obj = JSON.parse(body);
            resolve(obj.access_token);
        });
    });
}

// Overwrite file in Google Drive
function overWriting(object) {
    const metadata = {
        mimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
    };
    const url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/" + object.googleDocumentFileId + "?uploadType=multipart";
    const boundary = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    var data = "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"metadata\"\r\n";
    data += "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n";
    data += JSON.stringify(metadata) + "\r\n";
    data += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"sample.txt\"\r\n";
    data += "Content-Type: text/plain" + "\r\n\r\n";
    const payload = Buffer.concat([
        Buffer.from(data, "utf8"),
        new Buffer(object.textData, 'binary'),
        Buffer.from("\r\n--" + boundary + "--", "utf8"),
    ]);
    const options = {
        method: 'patch',
        url: url,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/related; boundary=" + boundary,
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + object.accessToken,
        },
        body: payload,
    };
    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
        console.log(body);
    });

}

async function main() {
    const serviceAccount = {
        privateKey: "###", // private_key of JSON file retrieved by creating Service Account
        clientEmail: "###", // client_email of JSON file retrieved by creating Service Account
    };
    var object = {
        googleDocumentFileId: "###", // Set the file ID of the existing Google Document
        textData: "hi there",
    };
    const accessToken = await getAccessToken(serviceAccount);
    if (accessToken) {
        object.accessToken = accessToken;
        overWriting(object);
    }
}

main();
```

Comment: @bluejayke I understood that you want to overwrite Google Document with a text value without using googleapis. For this situation, I added a sample script. Could you please confirm it? If this was not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: @bluejayke Did my additional sample script show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: @bluejayke Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.

Comment: `(node:3136) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.`

Comment: @BartusZak Thank you for your comment. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?