# Create folder returns undefined when trying to find file id

Tags: node.js, promise, google-drive-api

I am using Google drive API to create a folder and I want to return the id of this folder after creating it so I can make a folder tree. I don't understand why I am unable to do this, even using promises I consistently get the result of undefined for the id of the folder. This code returns undefined for the id of the folder. I don't want to use the list method to search the drive after creating the folder because it's slow. Any ideas?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google, run_v1} = require('googleapis');

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';


const CLIENT_NAME = 'Bowie, David';

const ROOT_FOLDER_LOCATION = '11ljl1lk1lk';


function getCreds(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
      if (err) {
        reject('error loading client secret');
      } else{
        resolve(JSON.parse(content));
      }
    })
  })
}

function authorize(creds){
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = creds.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
      if (err) {
        reject('this failed authorization');
      } else {
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
        resolve(oAuth2Client);
      }
    })
  })
}


function makeRoot(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
  var fileMetadata = {
    'name': CLIENT_NAME,
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
    'parents': [ROOT_FOLDER_LOCATION]
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    drive.files.create({
      resource: fileMetadata,
      fields: 'id'
    }, function(err, file) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve('Folder ID:', file.id);
      }
    })
  })

}


async function doWork() {
  
  try {
    const response = await getCreds();
    const oAuth2Client = await authorize(response);
    const rootFolder = await makeRoot(oAuth2Client);
    console.log(rootFolder);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  
}

doWork();
```

The only output I get is "undefined"...

Comment: if you're using promises and other `async`/`await` code, it's much easier to use node's [fs/promises](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_promises_api) module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When you want to retrieve the folder ID from the created new folder using googleapis for Node.js, in the case of your script, you can retrieve it using `file.data.id`. [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50373224), [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55335703)
- But, in your script, when `resolve('Folder ID:', file.id);` is run, `rootFolder` of `const rootFolder = await makeRoot(oAuth2Client);` is `Folder ID:`.

When you want to retrieve the value of `Folder ID:###folderId###`, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
resolve('Folder ID:', file.id);
```

#### To:

```
resolve("Folder ID:" + file.data.id);
```

- If you want to separate the values of `Folder ID:` and `###folderId###`, you can also use the following modification. In this case, you can retrieve the folder ID like `const [text, rootFolder] = await makeRoot(oAuth2Client);`.

  ```
    resolve(["Folder ID:", file.data.id]);
  ```

#### Reference:

- [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)

Comment: Thank you very much @Tanaike I appreciate it, very helpful.